# Read more/less button for multiple content - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use this javascript solution to add read more/less buttons to my testimonials. The problem is it only works for one button and not multiple as hoped. How can I make this code work for multiple buttons and not a single button?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {display: none;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because you're using a system with the `id` attribute. But ids need to be unique for them to work. Use classes instead. And when clicking on the buttons look for the `more` element in relation to the clicked button and toggle that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment `id's` needs to be unique, one of the kind. No way around that. If you have multiple, only the first one in DOM will work. So use classes instead. And learn how to target `event.target` in JavaScript. It will make everything easy.

```
  var dots = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".dots");
  var moreText = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".more");
  var btnText = event.target;
```

Please read here how to target [elements with events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp)

After you catch the clicked button with event as element, you just need to navigate to other elements from it. You can use among other things   [previousSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_previoussibling.asp) to get previous `p` and then  [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) to get wanted class inside it.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var dots = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".dots");
  var moreText = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".more");
  var btnText = event.target;

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>



  <h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>



  <h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at myFunction ((index):1582)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):560)`

Comment: @PhilipCron Take a good look at all the changes I did... You have working solution in-front of you. Did you changed all HTML ids  into classes?

Comment: Yes, I did that, I changed all HTML ids into classes and added your JavaScript. For some reason, I get that error code every time the button tries to fire.

Comment: is the HTML markup complicity the same as in code you posted in question? it has to be in order for this to work. it has to be `event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".more");`  it has to be button that is right after the paragraph and more  and dots classes needs to be inside it. If not, you need to target them correctly. @PhilipCron

Comment: Anyway your error means you are not getting the elements correctly

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score -1):

Using VanillaJS you can use something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".lessButton"). forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = () => {
        //Your action here   
    }
  });
  
  document.querySelectorAll(".moreButton"). forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = () => {
          //Your action here   
    }
  });

});
```

You can access element's attributes like ID and any data property you add to each button.